# Can I combine two ONNX graphs together, passing the output from one as input to another?

Tags: onnx, onnxruntime

I have a model, exported from pytorch, I'll call `main_model.onnx`. It has an input node I'll call `main_input` that expects a list of integers. I can load this in onnxruntime and send a list of ints and it works great.

I made another ONNX model I'll call `pre_model.onnx` with input `pre_input` and output `pre_output`. This preprocesses some text so input is the text, and `pre_output` is a list of ints, exactly as `main_model.onnx` needs for input.

My goal here is, using the Python `onnx.helper` tools, create one uber-model that accepts text as input, and runs through my `pre-model.onnx`, possibly some connector node (`Identity` maybe?), and then through `main_model.onnx` all in one big `combined.onnx` model.

I have tried using `pre_model.graph.node`+Identity connector+`main_model.graph.node` as nodes in a new graph, but the parameters exported from pytorch are lost this way. Is there a way to keep all those parameters and everything around, and export this one even larger combined ONNX model?

Comment: did you try to run those onnx models separately on onnxruntime feeding the output of the first model to the second? if so did it work?

Comment: Yep it worked. I can run them in sequence, just passing output from the pre_model to input of the main_model, and get the expected output from the main model.

Comment: why do you wanna combine them? why don't you just run them separately?

Comment: I'd like to just deliver a single .onnx file to someone to deploy. Even if it's simple, delivering two models also requires some communication about what order to run them in, confirm the input doesn't change between models, etc. so it's simpler just to share a single onnx model.

Comment: @maccam912 I did not find a straight forward solution, but adding nodes is possible to a current graph. You can refer to the code in this PR(https://github.com/onnx/onnx/pull/3264). I have to address the comments on that but it should give you decent idea to add the nodes in an onnx graph. Hope this helps.

Comment: @maccam912 do you have an example solution for this? I'm working on the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible to achieve albeit a bit tricky. You can explore the Python APIs offered by ONNX (https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/master/docs/PythonAPIOverview.md). This will allow you to load models to memory and you'll have to "compose" your combined model using the APIs exposed (combine both the GraphProto messages into one - this is easier said than done - you' ll have to ensure that you don't violate the onnx spec while doing this) and finally store the new Graphproto in a new ModelProto and you have your combined model. I would also run it through the onnx checker on completion to ensure the model is valid post its creation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have static size inputs, [sclblonnx](https://github.com/scailable/sclblonnx) package is an easy solution for merging Onnx models. However, it does not support dynamic size inputs.

For dynamic size inputs, one solution would be writing your own code using ONNX API as stated earlier.

Another solution would be converting the two ONNX models to a framework(Tensorflow or PyTorch) using tools like [onnx-tensorflow](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow) or [onnx2pytorch](https://github.com/ToriML/onnx2pytorch). Then pass the outputs of one network as inputs of the other network and export the whole network to Onnx format.